# How to allocate multidimensional array inside a class? It throws an error when row > column?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to write a board class for tic tac toe with large board size. I was trying to allocate memory dynamically it works for any array which has a size row <= column. However it throws error when row > column. Sometimes works while it allocates but it doesn't take when a value is assigned to it. Is there a way to check where the problem is? Also, should I just allocate a single dimensional array instead of two.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class BOARD{
  public:   
  static const int Max_row_size = 11;
  static const int Max_col_size = 14;
  int row;
  int col;
  char**board;

  char **initializeBoard(int row, int col);
  void printBoard(char ** board);
  BOARD(int row_size, int col_size);


};

BOARD::BOARD ( int row_size , int col_size ) {
      row = row_size;
      col = col_size;
      board = initializeBoard(row, col);
      printBoard(board);
    }

char **BOARD::initializeBoard ( int row_size , int col_size ) {
    row = row_size;
    col = col_size;

    char** playing_board;
    playing_board = new char*[col];

    for( int i = 0; i < col ; i++ ) {
        playing_board[i] = nullptr;
        playing_board[i]=new char[row];
    }
    char location = '1';
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < row; i++ ) {

        for( int j = 0; j < col; j++ ) {

            playing_board[i][j] = location;
        }
    }
    return playing_board;
}

int main(){


  BOARD x(5,4);
}
```

Comment: Unless it's a requirement to use raw non-owning pointers, why don't you use `std::vector` instead?

Comment: Just as a matter of style, `board` is a member of the class `BOARD`, so all of the member functions know about it. `initializeBoard` can work on `board` directly instead of using `playing_board` and returning `playing_board`. Same thing for `printBoard` -- it knows about `board`, so doesn't need to have a board passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've simply got your rows and columns mixed up when you initialise the array.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < row; i++ ) {

    for( int j = 0; j < col; j++ ) {
```

should be

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < col; i++ ) {

    for( int j = 0; j < row; j++ ) {
```

Allocating a single array is an alternative, personally I don't think there is much to choose between them. But the signifcant improvement you can make is to use `std::vector` instead of allocating the memory yourself. Unless you've been told specifically that you must use arrays you should use `std::vector` instead.

You can also change this

```
for( int i = 0; i < col ; i++ ) {
    playing_board[i] = nullptr;
    playing_board[i]=new char[row];
}
```

to this

```
for( int i = 0; i < col ; i++ ) {
    playing_board[i]=new char[row];
}
```

Assigning `nullptr` before assigning the allocated memory is unnecessary.